# Change find and replace every iteration

Tags: bash, unix, sed, iteration, replace

I have the following problem.

I have 3 directories each with a file `A.txt` in them.

Within `A.txt` I would like to replace `XXX` with a value. However, this value is different for each directory.

Here is a simple example using sed.

```
cd 1

sed 's/XXX/123/g' A.txt > B.txt

cd ..

cd 2 

sed 's/XXX/456/g' A.txt > B.txt

cd ..

cd 2 

sed 's/XXX/789/g' A.txt > B.txt

cd ..
```

I have approx 10,000 replacements to make so this is very inefficient.

Unfortunately the replacement values 123, 465 etc are not incremental so would have to be read from a file.

i.e `in.txt` contains 123 456 789

Is there any way that I can create a loop that will change the values to be replaced every iteration by referencing the file rows/columns or something else?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

DP

I've almost managed it using.

```
for dir in 1 2 3

do

while read I

do

cd $dir

sed -n 's/XXX/'"$I"'/p' A.txt > B.txt

cd ..

done

done < in.txt
```

But the loops are not right so it always results in the final value of in.txt in B.txt

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: how do you define which replacement is gonna be used by which file? e.g. "123' -> 1/B.txt but not for 2/B.txt ?

Comment: the replacements in in.txt are in order of the directories. i.e the first value goes in 1/A.txt 2nd in 2/A.txt etc

Comment: the 3rd cd should be cd 3 NOT cd 2

Answer (score 1):

`sed` takes a file name as a script:

```
sed -f sed.script
```

Some versions of `sed` (notably on (older?) HP-UX) have limits on how many lines can appear in a `sed` script - and the limit is about 100 there.  Most versions of `sed` do not have an overt limit, though 10,000 substitutions might run into the limit.

You should consider generating a set of scripts, `dir1.sed`, `dir2.sed` and `dir3.sed`.

You can then write:

```
for dir in 1 2 3
do
    (
    cd $dir &&
    sed -f ../dir$dir.sed A.txt > B.txt
    )
done
```

Note that if you need to make multiple passes (because you had to create `dir1.1.sed`, `dir1.2.sed`, ... `dir1.N.sed`) then you need to arrange to edit B.txt on the second pass, etc.

Note the use of the `(...)` sub-shell to isolate the driving script from the `cd` operations.  There's then no need for `cd ..`.  I look askance at any script that contains `...; cd somedir; ...; cd ..`.

Some versions of `sed` (GNU inspired) support in-place file modification: `sed -i -f dir1.sed A.txt`.  Otherwise, if you need to keep `A.txt` around, make a copy first, then edit the copy repeatedly:

```
for dir in 1 2 3
do
    (cd $dir; cp A.txt B.txt)
done

for dir in 1 2 3
do
    for script in 1 2 3 4 ... N
    do
        (
        cd $dir
        sed -f ../dir$dir.$script.sed B.txt > C.txt
        mv C.txt B.txt
        )
    done
done
```

The contents of the `sed` script files are lines like:

```
s/XXX/123/
s/YYY/234/
s/zzz/abc/
```

etc - they are `sed` commands.

Comment: Almost but that still requires creating a lot of .sed files. What I would like is a combination of your answer and the one from asf107. i.e. reading the values to be replaced from a single file then looping them over a sed function.

Comment: Probably one file per directory...if you have a simple way of mapping 'from' and 'to' information in a file, then write a `sed` script to generate the `sed` script that will be run on the data.  For example, if the information is in `map-file` in the format '`<old><space><new>`', then you can write a script: `sed -e 's%\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)%s/\1/\2/%' map-file > sed.script`.

Comment: I was doing this sort of stuff 20 years ago on HP-UX, with similar volumes of mapping data.  This predated the internet (or, at least, I couldn't get GNU software onto the client's machines), so I ended up writing a specialized program to do the job.  Last modified in May 1991 - not converted to prototypes (they were still not widely available back then; the standard was only a a year and a half or so old).  It is unusual in that it picks up the data to be mapped, and then does a binary search through the possible substitutions to pick up the relevant one; there is but one.